# How can I add bootstrap 4.0.0 Collapse to an html table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hello I was wondering how could I add collapsable elements to an html table?

My code is this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th class="d-none d-md-table-cell" scope="col">Old Permalink</th>
      <th class="d-none d-md-table-cell" scope="col">New Permalink</th>
      <th class="text-center d-none d-md-table-cell" scope="col">Remove</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="d-none d-md-table-row">
      <th scope="row" data-label="Type">301</th>
      <td data-label="Old Permalink">XX</td>
      <td data-label="New Permalink">XX</td>
      <td align="center" data-label="Delete Record">
        <button name="delete0" value="19" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-md-none">
      <th>301</th>
      <td colspan="2" data-label="Old Permalink">
        <strong>Old Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-label="New Permalink">
        <strong>New Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td align="right">
        <button name="delete0" value="19" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none d-md-table-row">
      <th scope="row" data-label="Type">301</th>
      <td data-label="Old Permalink">XX</td>
      <td data-label="New Permalink">XX</td>
      <td align="center" data-label="Delete Record">
        <button name="delete0" value="20" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-md-none">
      <th>301</th>
      <td colspan="2" data-label="Old Permalink">
        <strong>Old Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-label="New Permalink">
        <strong>New Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td align="right">
        <button name="delete0" value="20" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none d-md-table-row">
      <th scope="row" data-label="Type">301</th>
      <td data-label="Old Permalink">XX</td>
      <td data-label="New Permalink">XX</td>
      <td align="center" data-label="Delete Record">
        <button name="delete0" value="21" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-md-none">
      <th>301</th>
      <td colspan="2" data-label="Old Permalink">
        <strong>Old Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-label="New Permalink">
        <strong>New Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td align="right">
        <button name="delete0" value="21" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none d-md-table-row">
      <th scope="row" data-label="Type">301</th>
      <td data-label="Old Permalink">XX</td>
      <td data-label="New Permalink">XX</td>
      <td align="center" data-label="Delete Record">
        <button name="delete0" value="22" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-md-none">
      <th>301</th>
      <td colspan="2" data-label="Old Permalink">
        <strong>Old Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-label="New Permalink">
        <strong>New Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td align="right">
        <button name="delete0" value="22" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I am looking for is to be able to press the `TYPE` "301" row and collapse the rest of the table content.

IMG EXAMPLES:

Pressing the Highlighted 301 text/row should collapse out the rest of the data.

[image]

IMG after data was collapsed by pressing the 301 text/row:

[image]

*Thanks in advance for your time end effort, please make sure to include any references about bootstrap css or js file ( I have included the whole CSS and JS folders included in the 4.0.0 bootstrap ZIP )*

Comment: Firstly, upgrade from 4.0.0 to 4.x latest. 4.0.0 is comically old and _many_ bugfixes and improvements have been released since.

Comment: [Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/collapse/) requires a trigger/container relationship which isn't really available in a table. Is there some reason you're required to use a table?

Comment: Bootstrap does not have that capability for tables. Use something like on this site: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-html-table-expand-on-click-using-javascript/

Comment: Hello @Lisa , Thank you for sharing an alternative! I am getting this error returned after trying to implement this method. Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLCollection]

Comment: Got an answer for you coming up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap does not have this functionality. Here is an option for you that does what you want. Bootstrap wasn't cooperating with this, so if you want to see it with styling, go here: https://codepen.io/shikkaba/pen/qBKbrWm

On click of a tr that is in tbody, all siblings with class of .option are hidden, and the next item is unhidden. All of the "answers" have to have the class to hide them already applied on them for this to work properly as this is literally just toggling a class.

```js
$("table tbody tr.option").click(function() {
  // Show current `tr` and hide others
  $(this).siblings(".option").toggleClass("hide");
  $(this).next().toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th class="d-none d-md-table-cell" scope="col">Old Permalink</th>
      <th class="d-none d-md-table-cell" scope="col">New Permalink</th>
      <th class="text-center d-none d-md-table-cell" scope="col">Remove</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="d-none d-md-table-row option">
      <th scope="row" data-label="Type">301</th>
      <td data-label="Old Permalink">XX</td>
      <td data-label="New Permalink">XX</td>
      <td align="center" data-label="Delete Record">
        <button name="delete0" value="19" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none d-md-table-row  hide">
      <th>301</th>
      <td data-label="Old Permalink">
        <strong>Old Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td data-label="New Permalink">
        <strong>New Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <button name="delete0" value="19" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none d-md-table-row option">
      <th scope="row" data-label="Type">302</th>
      <td data-label="Old Permalink">XX</td>
      <td data-label="New Permalink">XX</td>
      <td align="center" data-label="Delete Record">
        <button name="delete0" value="19" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none d-md-table-row  hide">
      <th>302</th>
      <td data-label="Old Permalink">
        <strong>Old Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td data-label="New Permalink">
        <strong>New Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <button name="delete0" value="19" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none d-md-table-row  option">
      <th scope="row" data-label="Type">303</th>
      <td data-label="Old Permalink">XX</td>
      <td data-label="New Permalink">XX</td>
      <td align="center" data-label="Delete Record">
        <button name="delete0" value="19" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="d-none d-md-table-row hide">
      <th>303</th>
      <td data-label="Old Permalink">
        <strong>Old Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td data-label="New Permalink">
        <strong>New Permalink:</strong> XX
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <button name="delete0" value="19" class="btn btn-danger grmlt-js-btn">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello Lisa,
Thank you for helping me out with this problem, I changed your code just a little bit and it worked like a charm the logic behind the solution is in your answer!